# Array element values, element addresses, and pointer increment

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, memory-address

This a very basic concept. But, I get confused generally. Help me.

Case 1:

For the below code:

```
int oneDArray[] = {1,2,3};
cout<<&oneDArray<<endl;
cout<<oneDArray<<endl;
cout<<&oneDArray+1<<endl;
cout<<oneDArray+1<<endl;
```

Output is :

```
0x28fef4
0x28fef4
0x28ff00
0x28fef8
```

Why is there a difference in the incremented values?

Case 2:

```
  int arr[2][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
  cout<<&arr<<endl;
  cout<<arr<<endl;
  cout<<*arr<<endl;

  cout<<&arr+1<<endl;
  cout<<arr+1<<endl;
  cout<<*arr+1<<endl;
```

Output is:

```
0x28fee8
0x28fee8
0x28fee8
0x28ff00
0x28fef4
0x28feec
```

Why is the output same for arr & *arr? (How it works internally)
Why is there a difference in the incremented values?

Comment: What else are you expecting from it? Name of an array already returns the address of first element. Adding & to the name attempts to make it a pointer and return the address, which is still the same, but i would say weird. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I'd be rather interested in another "why": **Why haven't you used Google or a search,** alternatively **why haven't you read that C tutorial attentively?**

Comment: @fayyazki I'm not using it, I'm just understanding the concept. I want to know how it works internally. Also, what about the case two with 2D array?

Comment: @PaulDinh I've recomposed the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your single-dimension array:

```
//starting at memory address: 0x28FEF4
int My_Array[3] = {1,2,3};

//memory dumping, each 'int' element takes 4 bytes, 
//high bytes are at higher addresses
0x28FEF4 01 00 00 00
0x28FEF8 02 00 00 00
0x28FEFC 03 00 00 00
```

This is the translation from C language to English language:

```
My_Array     = (address) of-the (first-byte) of (My_Array)
My_Array[0]  = (value)   of-the (element-at-index-0)
My_Array[k]  = (value)   of-the (element-at-index-k)

&My_Array    = (address) of-the (first-byte) of (My_Array)
&My_Array[0] = (address) of-the (first-byte) of (element-at-index-0)
&My_Array[k] = (address) of-the (first-byte) of (element-at-index-k)

*My_Array    = (value) pointed-by (My_Array)
*My_Array[0] = (value) pointed-by (My_Array[0])
*My_Array[k] = (value) pointed-by (My_Array[k])

The values of 'My_Array' and '&My_Array' are always identical for array type
but there's a difference when using them with mathematical operators.
My_Array is a pointer to 'int' type, while &My_Array is a pointer 
to 'int[3]' type.  When incremented, the values added in are sizeof(int) 
and sizeof(int[3]) respectively.

The last two notations: *My_Array[0] and *My_Array[k]
are valid in mathematical sense but not valid in C language when using 
with single-dimension array because C langugae doesn't allow using 
'int' value as pointer.
```

Explanation for the output result of your case 1:

```
(&My_Array) is identical to (My_Array)  = 
0x28FEF4

(My_Array)  is identical to (&My_Array) = 
0x28FEF4

(&My_Array+1) = 0x28FEF4 + sizeof(int[3]) = 0x28FEF4 + 12 = 
0x28FF00

(My_Array+1)  = 0x28FEF4 + sizeof(int)    = 0x28FEF4 + 4  = 
0x28FEF8
```

Apply my notes above to your second case, with these attentions:

```
(1) Value of element in single dimension array is the base type. Eg:
    int My_Array[3]; //base type is 'int'

(2) Value of element in multiple dimension array is either pointer 
    or base type. Eg:
    int My_Array[2][3][4]; //base type is 'int'

    My_Array is a pointer to 'int' type        
    My_Array[i] is a pointer to 'int' type
    My_Array[i][j] is a pointer to 'int' type
    My_Array[i][j][k] is an 'int' value

    &My_Array is a pointer to 'int[2][3][4]'
    &My_Array[i] is a pointer to 'int[3][4]' 
    &My_Array[i][j] is a pointer to 'int[4]'
    &My_Array[i][j][k] is a pointer to 'int'

(3) Values of 'My_Array' and '&My_Array' are always equal,
    however, when dealing with operators, they work differently.
    Eg.
    int My_Array[2][3][4]; //base type is 'int'

    '&My_Array' here is a pointer to 'int[2][3][4]', but
    'My_Array' is a pointer to base type 'int'.

(4) A pointer is always incremented by the size of the type 
    that it points to. 'int' has size of 4 bytes.
    Eg.
    int My_Array[2];          //type size = (2)*4
    int My_Array[2][3];       //type size = (2*3)*4
    int My_Array[2][3][4];    //type size = (2*3*4)*4
    int My_Array[2][3][4][5]; //type size = (2*3*4*5)*4
```

Comment: Once, I asked a very silly question from a Prof. A, he just shouted at me "You studied nothing, just go back and find it in your notes". Same question, I asked from another Prof B, he said "I'm a little busy, lets meet after lunch time, I'll explain you". And, he did explain me. The difference was not in their knowledge but in their attitudes. One was an Assit. Prof other was the Director.